# exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: Failed to dup() QSRI sync fd : sterror: Bad file descriptor errno: 9

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I was using unity 2021.3.22f1 and trying to deploy my apk file. The game work perfectly in editor, but appear some bug in mobile.

When I test my game in android studio, the only error appear in my console is:

`exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: Failed to dup() QSRI sync fd : sterror: Bad file descriptor errno: 9`

Anyone has any idea about this problem? Since there are no information about this bug on the internet.

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key C:\Users\Admin\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_34.avd (attempted merging values Pixel 2 API 34 and Pixel 2 API 34)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.VirtualDeviceTableWatcherListener.virtualDevicesChanged(VirtualDeviceTableWatcherListener.java:35)
    at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.EventListenerLists.fire(EventListenerLists.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.VirtualDeviceWatcher.fireVirtualDevicesChanged(VirtualDeviceWatcher.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.VirtualDeviceWatcher.lambda$fireVirtualDevicesChanged$1(VirtualDeviceWatcher.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:36)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:756)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```